# High Chart is not visible on dynamic data

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using simple line high chart. It is working fine static arrays like if i assign series with data array `series=[10,20,30]`, but assigning a variable like `series = data`; where data variable value fetch value from api getgymgoer() then graph  is not visible. I checked many answers making highchart with dynamic data but they are not working in my case.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth/auth.service';


HC_exporting(Highcharts);


@Component({
  selector: 'app-weight-chart',
  templateUrl: './weight-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weight-chart.component.scss']
})
export class WeightChartComponent implements OnInit {
  // chartOptions = {};
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  user: any;
  constructor(private authService:AuthService) { }
  gymgoerweight = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.user=this.authService.getUser();
    this.getgymgoer();
  }
  getgymgoer(){
    this.authService.getCurrentUser(this.user.id).subscribe((response:any)=>{
      this.gymgoerweight=response.weight;
      console.log("------goer weight from streak-------");
      console.log(this.gymgoerweight);
    })
  }

  weight:any=[10,20,30,40];
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    // start chart  
    colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572',
           '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
  chart:{
    events: {
      load: function() {
        
        var series = this.series[0],
        last = series.data[series.data.length - 1];
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
      stops: [
        [0, '#2e2e2c'],
        [1, '#2e2e2c']
      ]
    }
  },
    title: {
      text: '<h3 style="color:white; margin-left:0px; text-transform:uppercase">Weight Chart</h3>'
    },
  
    subtitle: {
      
      text: '<h5 style="color:white">Source: Open.fit</h5>'
    },
  
    yAxis: {
      title: {
       
        text: ' <h5 style="color:white">Active user count</h5>'
      }
    },
  
   
  
    // legend: {
    //   layout: 'vertical',
    //   align: 'right',
    //   verticalAlign: 'middle'
    // },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2022, 0, 4),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000*30 
        // 24 * 3600 * 1000 One day expression
    }
    },
  
    series: [
      {
      type:'line',
      data: this.gymgoerweight
      },
  ],
  
    responsive: {
      rules: [{
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 500,
        },
        chartOptions: {
          legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            
          }
        }
      }]
    }
    // end chart
  }


}
```

here on calling getCurrentUser api in console i am getting data in gymgoerweight sucessfull but when I am assigning it to series then chart is not visible. Any solution?

Comment: Hi @Nitin Saini, You need to update your chart when the data is received. Did you use the `highcharts-angular` wrapper? If so, please check this simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-update-optimal-way?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts of how you can do that.

Comment: yes, I am using. thanks for sharing

Comment: No problem. Please let me know if you are still having problems with applying dynamic data.